# El icono agregado por javascript no se visualiza hasta refrescar

Tags: html, css, icons

estoy añadiendo un icon a un botón creado desde javascript

```
let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fi-xwsuxl-bin" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
```

Cuando se agrega el botón a el html no se visualiza el icono hasta refrescar pagina, al inspeccionar puedo ver que se agrega perfectamente el  junto con la clase pero hasta refrescar se agrega el svg que debe ir dentro de la etiqueta

Answer (score 0):

Creaste el elemento pero no lo añadiste a ninguna parte del html. Para esto debes ocupar el metodo `appendChild`.

Por ejemplo, aquí lo añado al body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
      deleteButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>';

      document.body.appendChild(deleteButton);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```